# How to remove voice or vocal from a song just like karaoke app?

Tags: android, voice

Iam doing a app just karaoke app.I have been scratching my head for the past week how  to remove voice or vocal from song and to add  our voice in that song just like karaoke apps...
Please help me.

Comment: It's very difficult to remove vocal mathematically because vocal voice has alot of components . I guess you have to use neural networks.there's alot of  papers about it specially with deep learning neural networks.